# Find and delete rows up to rowindex of a value in an HTML Table Collection

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, functional-programming

I have a monthly html calendar table like this:

```
<table id="a">
  <tr><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td></tr>
  <tr><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need a functional solution to delete rows from the bottom to "7", essentially leaving just the first week. My approach is to convert the collection to an array, find the rowindex which results in the number of `deleterow(-1)` to run on the live table.

```
const ta = [...document.querySelectorAll('table#a>*>tr')]
  .map(row => [...row.querySelectorAll('td,th')]
  .map(cell => cell.innerText) );
```

outputs a multi-dimensional array, which can then be looped over...

```
for (let i = 0; i < ta.length; i++) {
  if(ta[i].some(e => e === '7')) console.log(ta.length-i);
};

// 4
```

however chaining `.some(e => e === '7')` always returns `false`. I was hoping to add something like `.some(function (elem, i) {return elem === '7' && ~(index = i);` to get the index of the row where it is found.

Is there a fully functional way to accomplish this?

Comment: Why don't you loop over rows...then loop over cells within each row until you find the one you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ta.find(row=>row.some(e=>e==="7"))` will get you the actual sub-array containing the "7" and `ta.indexOf(...)` will give you its index in the outer array:

```js
const ta = [...document.querySelectorAll('table#a tr')]
  .map(row => [...row.children].map(cell => cell.textContent) );
  
let index = ta.indexOf(ta.find(row=>row.some(e=>e==="7")));

console.log(index)
```

```html
<table id="a">
  <tr><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td><td>15</td><td>16</td><td>17</td><td>18</td><td>19</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>23</td><td>24</td><td>25</td><td>26</td><td>27</td></tr>
  <tr><td>28</td><td>29</td><td>30</td><td>31</td><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Works great Carsten, and thank you for cleaning up the querySelector/map statement. Just out of curiosity, can indexOf/find be chained to create a one-liner?